# Linq - Getting second value only if != null

Tags: c#, linq

I have this method for an autocomplete function.
I want to show the address and `-` character only when the `address != null`.

```
public JsonResult GetClients(string term)
{
     List<string> ClientsJson;
     ClientsJson = db.Clients.Where(x => x.Name.StartsWith(term))
                             .Select(selector: x => x.Name + " - " + x.Address1).ToList();

     return Json(ClientsJson, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could find below another way to solve your problem using a **Ternary Operator** , it's not the more efficient way but ,it's stay the more a simple .

```
public JsonResult GetClients(string term)
{
   List<string> ClientsJson;
   ClientsJson = db.Clients.Where(x => x.Name.StartsWith(term))
                             .Select(selector: x => x.Name + ((x.Adress1 == null) ? " " : "-" + x.Adress1)).ToList();

   return Json(ClientsJson, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Comment: @CSP literally a late copy of my answer but ok.

Answer (score 5):

#### Little dirty but this can work.

```
public JsonResult GetClients(string term)
{
     List<string> ClientsJson;
     ClientsJson = db.Clients.Where(x => x.Name.StartsWith(term))
                             .Select(selector: x => $"{x.Name}{(x.Address1 != null ? $" - {x.Address1}" : "")}").ToList();

     return Json(ClientsJson, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

#### Explanation:

String starting with `$` is a [string interpolation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated).
It allows to insert variables/computed values right into the string.

Let's dissect my example:

```
$"{x.Name}{(x.Address1 != null ? $" - {x.Address1}" : "")}"
```

First we add `x.Name` to the string.
Then we add computed value.
`condition ? true-value : false-value` will return first value (`true-value`) if condition is true and otherwise.

We check if `x.Address1` is not null. If it is - we return `$" - {x.Address1}"` and we return empty string otherwise.

Parentheses around just helping compiler to understand us better. We say that `(this expression is one thing)`.

#### Update:

You're trying to request your autocompletition data from database.
It uses `LINQ-to-SQL` features that tries to convert your C# code into SQL.

`.Where()` will work perfectly, but `LINQ-to-SQL` doesn't support string concatenation (adding two string together).

You probably need to:

- First select your data using LINQ
- Replace `.Select` method with `foreach` loop and build array of strings yourself.

#### Also again..

..don't use JsonResult if you running ASP.NET Core.
You can return normal objects and they will transform to JSON automatically.

Comment: Adding explanation soon.

Comment: Are there any compiler errors? Runtime exceptions? Or it just doesn't work without any errors?

Comment: I get : `jquery.js:10254 GET https://localhost:44381/Home/GetClients?term=test 500` in the console.

Comment: @John No not really, very new to both linq, c# and mvc. Thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: `500` in the end means `Internal Server Error` (it's a HTTP status code). your server encountered runtime exception (error while running). Please check your webserver console. It will probably contain error details.

Comment: `LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String Format(System.String, System.Object, System.Object)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.`

Comment: Allright, Thanks for the help! I am running ASP.Net MVC 5.